# NoUiSlider - Update input value multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, nouislider

I've been using jQuery for the majority of my development so far, and I'm hitting a road block using vanilla Javascript to update NoUiSlider.

Basically I have it creating multiple sliders with the following code:

```
function createSlider ( slide ) {
    noUiSlider.create(sliders[slide], {
        start: 0,
        connect: "lower",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        step: 1,
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 240
        }
    });
}

var sliders = $('.slider');
for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {
    createSlider(i);
}
```

And this is all fine and dandy, and I realize I'm supposed to listen to the event of it changing by using `update`, but I'm very unfamiliar with a **DRY** method of setting up corresponding `input` values... let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" value="0" />
<div class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" value="0" />
<div class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" value="0" />
```

How would I go about adding an event listener to update the next `input` after the slider that was being modified?

I'd assume I'd do something along the lines of:

```
(howToTargetEachInput).addEventListener('change', function(){
    (howToTargetEquivilantSlider).noUiSlider.set(this.value);
});
```

But I have no idea how to use a repeating listener without using a bunch of IDs and whatnot. Any help is appreciated.

Play here: http://jsfiddle.net/z83oz9np/9/

---

### Update / Solution

I wrote an bind function that was called during the creation of the sliders as so:

```
    function bindValues(slider, input){
        slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
            input.value = values[handle];
        });
        input.addEventListener('change', function(){
            slider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
        });
    }
    var sliders = $('.slider');
    var inputs = $('input');
    for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {
        noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
            start: 0,
            connect: "lower",
            orientation: "horizontal",
            step: 1,
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 240
            }
        });
        bindValues(sliders[i], inputs[i]);
    }
```

Comment: What is this slider, is it some sort of image slider? Coz i cant see anything in js fiddle apart from three input fields.

Comment: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ - Its a lightweight alternative to the jQuery UI Slider. Are you not seeing the sliding bars as well as the input fields...?

Comment: Beautiful solution. You should add this as an answer to this question, then mark it as the actual answer. That'll allow me to up-vote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jQuery, then its easier to stick with it.

Here is how you can achieve this:-

```js
function createSlider (slide) {
    var slider = noUiSlider.create(sliders[slide], {
        start: 0,
        connect: "lower",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        step: 1,
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 240
        }
    });
    
    // add the slider object to the slider element
    // using data for future reference
    $(sliders[slide]).data('slider', slider);
    
    slider.on('change', function( values, handle ) {
        // on change of the slider, find the next element and set its value
        $(event.target).closest('.slider').next().val(values[handle])
    });
}

var sliders = $('.slider');
for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {
 createSlider(i);
}

$('.slider-input').change(function(){
   // on input change, get the slider from the previous element using data
   // now we have the slider object to call set.
   $(this).prev().data('slider').set(this.value);
});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://refreshless.com/noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider.js"></script>
<link href="https://refreshless.com/noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" class="slider-input" value="0" />
<div class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" class="slider-input" value="0" />
<div class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" class="slider-input" value="0" />

<p>How do I set up the inputs to reflect what the slider's value is...?</p>
```

Comment: Ahh nice... I didn't realise the only inputs on the page was going to be for the sliders. Good solution!